# What do you usually do when waiting for code to compile

Tags: compilation

I've got this piece of code that took about 1 to 2 minutes to compile. What do you usually do in your free time while you are compiling code?

Comment: Have mock sword fights on rolling chairs.

Comment: 1-2 minutes is plenty of time to load Stack Overflow and accept some answers...

Comment: I vote to close off-topic questions.

Comment: thkala: no, it should be on programmers.se.

Comment: @Ignacio - *mock* sword fights?  Why not the real thing?

Answer (score 4):

[image]